# Close while loop running in file A from file B in python on windows/linux

Tags: python, linux, windows

I am trying to figure out a way to close a running script, let’s call it A.py. The A.py can’t have any `input()` inside etc. I thought that the best way of closing script A.py would be running command to break main while loop in A.py from other script e.g. B.py. I don’t know how I can perform it. I need a solution for windows and Linux or universal one.

A.py:

```
import time
import asyncio
from image_procesing.recognizer import Recognizer
from configuration.config import ProgramData
from external_services_communication.commincation import Knx, KnxAndInflux, InfluxDb
from image_procesing.video_capturer import Capturer

recognizer = Recognizer(ProgramData.coco_data)
capturer = Capturer(ProgramData.connection_string)
start_time = None
last_count = None

while True:
    success, frame = capturer.get_status_and_frame()

    if not success:
        break

    # ... Further code not relevant to the question 

        start_time = time.time()

capturer.close()
exit()
```

I assume that in B.py should be code that changes a True in while loop inside A.py to False, but I don’t know how to do it.

I would be pleased If someone could help me with that. I couldn’t find a similar question so maybe it will be beneficial for other people as well.

To sum up, I would like to have a solution to safely close running file, e.g. by breaking while loop.

Comment: So how do you run the script `A.py`?

Comment: The file will be run by command: python 'path to A.py'.  Now I run it in pycharm but it's only temporally.

Comment: So, just press `ctrl-C` when you want it to stop?

Comment: But it's gonna be run on Linux server. Will it be a problem?

Comment: I think you can use `ctrl-C` on Linux too. (I think that pressing the stop button in pycharm simulates ctrl-c from the user).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this example code to show how you can have work done in a separate thread, leaving the main thread to run the `input()` command so that the user can come back to the command line process, type `stop`, for example, and have the thread (each time it finishes each piece of work) check a queue for the stop command.

```
import time
import queue
import threading

def background(q):
    print('bg started ...')
    t = 0
    while True:
        # degenerate example of doing work which takes time
        time.sleep(1)
        t += 1
        try:
            result = q.get(block=False)
            q.put(f'{result} - {t=}')
            return
        except queue.Empty:
            pass



q = queue.Queue()
bg = threading.Thread(target=background, args=(q,))
bg.start()
time.sleep(2)
while True:
    response = input('Enter Command: ').lower()
    if response == 'stop':
        q.put(response)
        bg.join()
        print(q.get())
        break
```

Example session:

```
bg started ...
Enter Command: help
Enter Command: foo
Enter Command: stop
stop - t=12
```

Comment: Thanks, Quamrana for your answer, which provided me a different outlook for my case.